# Explain that a function has a given Jacobian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $W$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with elements $w_{ij}$, and that $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a column vector with elements $b_{i}$. We know that the Jacobian matrix to the affine transformation $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) = W\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$ is $\mathbf{F}'(\mathbf{x}) = W$. We are now looking at the function
$\mathbf{G}: \mathbb{R}^{(n^2+n)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by

$\mathbf{G}(w_{11},\ldots,w_{1n},\ldots,w_{n1},\ldots,w_{nn},\ldots,b_1,\ldots,b_n) = W\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$

We are looking at the elements in $W$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as variables (with these listed row by row, from left to right), and $\mathbf{x}$ as a constant. Explain that the Jacobian matrix to $\mathbf{G}$ is

[image]

where $O$ stands for a vector or matrix with only zeros. Above, $\mathbf{x}$ is therefore repeated on each row.

When I find the Jacobian matrix to the function, I get the exact same one, except I get $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ in the diagonal to the left. How do I get this to be the transposed of $\mathbf{x}$ instead? Do they use the transposed to match the dimensions?

Comment: Let $$x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$$ and let $$y=Wx+b=\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{pmatrix}.$$  When you get $x_j$ on the right side, it appears as $$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial \star}$$ for some $i$ and for some input variable $\star$. For what $i$ and what variable $\star$ are you getting $x_j$?

Comment: What the dimensions of the answer you are getting?

Comment: No, the $i$th row of $G(...)$ is $\sum_k w_{ik}x_k + b_i$, so $[{\partial G(...) \over \partial w_{ij}}]_{i } = x_j$.

Comment: @copper.hat You have to calculate $$\Bigl[\frac{\partial G(\ldots)}{\partial w_{p,q}}\Bigr]_i$$ for every $p,q$. Not just $p=i$. That's the issue that OP is missing.

Comment: @user469053 The formula shows that the entry in the Jacobian is $x^T$.

Comment: Yes. If that is what you intended to say, then I believe your comment is not clearly written.

Comment: Perhaps it was not clearly read :-).

Comment: You say nothing about why you're ignoring lots of indices.

Comment: Again, the OP was asking why $x^T$ and not $x$. I added a comment that discriminates, not a compete formula.

Comment: It discriminates in what way?

Comment: See Yggdrasil's answer below, it shows the formula I wrote above in a nice clear easy to understand way :-).

Comment: I get xj if i = j. Isn't that right? @user469053

Comment: I understand the formula almost.. However I though $\mathbf{x}$ was a vector in n dimensions and not a scalar? @copper.hat

Comment: @math.lover $x=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$. I am not sure why you think it is a scalar?

Comment: @copper.hat not that one, but the x in the beginning in $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) = W\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$. I thought it was $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n$

Comment: @math.lover sorry, I don't follow either of your last two comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the given matrix product as follows
$$ Wx + b = \begin{bmatrix} w_1^T \\ \vdots \\ w_n^T \end{bmatrix} \cdot x + b $$
$$ =  \begin{bmatrix} w_1^T \cdot x + b_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n^T \cdot x + b_n \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} x^T \cdot w_1 + b_1 \\ \vdots \\ x^T \cdot w_n + b_n \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ = \begin{bmatrix} x^T & & &\vert & 1 & & \\
 & \ddots & & \vert & & \ddots & \\
 & & x^T & \vert & & &1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \\ b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}.$$
The jacobian with respect to $w_i$ and $b_i$ can then be directly calculated from the last expression and is identical to the one provided by you.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought $\mathbf{x}$ was a vector in n dimensions? Why is it a scalar?

Comment: I should have been more explicit. I used $w_i$ as shorthand notation for $$ w_i = \begin{bmatrix} w_{i,1} \\ \vdots \\ w_{i,n} \end{bmatrix}.$$  Therefore $w_i^T$ corresponds to the $i$-th row vector of $W$.

Comment: I figured it out and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the more general case
$\mathbf{g}
=\mathbf{Wx+b}$
where $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$.

The differential writes
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mathbf{g}
&=& (d\mathbf{W}) \mathbf{x} \\
&=& (\mathbf{x}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_M) 
d \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{W}) \\
&=& (\mathbf{x}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_M) 
\mathbf{K}_{M,N} d \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{W}^T) \\
&=& 
(\mathbf{I}_M \otimes \mathbf{x}^T) 
 d \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{W}^T)
\end{eqnarray}

Last line comes from the properties of permutation matrices:
$$
(\mathbf{I}_M \otimes \mathbf{x}^T )
=
\mathbf{K}_{1M}
(\mathbf{x}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_M)
\mathbf{K}_{M,N}
$$
and
$\mathbf{K}_{1M}=\mathbf{I}_M$.

The Jacobian writes
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{W}^T)}
= \mathbf{I}_M \otimes \mathbf{x}^T
$$ which is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w_{i,j}$ be the row $i$, column $j$ entry of $W$. Let $$b=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix},$$ $$x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{pmatrix},$$ and $$y=Wx+b=\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $$y_i=\sum_{i=1}^n w_{i,j}x_j+b_i.$$

We know that for any $1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n$, $$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial b_j}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : i = j \\ 0 & : i\neq j.\end{array}\right.$$  This gives the $n\times n$ identity matrix to the right of the bar.

For every $1\leqslant i,p,q\leqslant n$, we want to compute $$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial w_{p,q}}=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \frac{\partial w_{i,j}}{\partial w_{p,q}} +  \frac{\partial b_i}{\partial w_{p,q}}.$$   Since the $w$s and $b$s are all independent variables, we get $\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial w_{p,q}}=0$ always, and $$\frac{\partial w_{i,j}}{\partial w_{p,q}} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : i=p,j=q \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$$  So if $p\neq i$, we get only zero values (these are all the zeros to the left of the bar, and they come in groups of $n$, one for each $1\leqslant q\leqslant n$).  When $i=p$, we get $$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial w_{i,q}}=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\frac{\partial w_{i,j}}{\partial w_{i,q}} = x_q,$$ since the $j\neq q$ terms are all zero and the $j=q$ term is $x_q$ times $\frac{\partial w_{i,q}}{\partial w_{i,q}}=1$.  So for a fixed $i$, we will get **each** $x_q$ value as $q$ runs from $1$ to $n$.

To the left of the bar, we have $n^2$ columns, which we group into $n$ sets of $n$. On row $i$, only the $i^{th}$ group of columns will have non-zero values (corresponding to $p=i$), and the values in those $n$ columns will be $x_1,\ldots, x_n$, as $q$ ranges over these values while $p=i$ is held fixed.